# Integrating JaCoCo with SONAR for unit and integration test coverage

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, jacoco

Has any one tried configuring JaCoCo to dump the coverage of unit and integration tests in 2 different files, for SONAR to use them, using ANT build?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, generating the report for both unit tests and integration tests. This solution is using the `append` strategy.

Please note that in order to work properly on the `apply` strategy, the phases should be executed sequentially (if the `mvn test` and `mvn verify -DskipUnitTests` will be executed in parallel there is possible to not work fine).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>

    <configuration>
        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>

        <!-- This line is very important, because allows to append the results to the `jacoco_aggregation.exec` report. -->
        <append>true</append>

        <!-- DestFile is the file defined, where the `prepare-agent` will pe publishing the result of analysis,
             for the defined `phase`. In our case is executed initially and to the `pre-integration-test` phase. -->
        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco_aggregation.exec</destFile>

        <!-- DataFile is the path from where the `report` goal will be reading the report
             in order to create the `outputDirectory` .xml file. -->
        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco_aggregation.exec</dataFile>

        <!-- To the goal `report`, will be reading the report from `dataFile` path and will be publishing the result,
             to the `outputDirectory` path as an .xml file.
             In our case, the report is generated for two times:
                 - first time after the `test` phase
                 - second time after the `post-integration-test` phase -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
             is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        
        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report `jacoco.xml` is generated once the unit tests were executed.
             Executes the `report` goal after the `post-integration-test` phase. -->
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
             is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        
        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report `jacoco.xml` is generated once the integration tests were executed.
             Executes the `report` goal after the `post-integration-test` phase. -->
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once the reports are generated, you can execute the sonar commant to apply the reports.

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths="target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
```