# Get IT test in Sonar trough maven

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

Gooday,
I’m trying to get my IT in to the test coverage in sonar. I have a multi module project and I want this to work for all the modules. So as far as I got it through the documentation I found:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven (witch are outdated btw)
- http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html
- [Integrating JaCoCo with SONAR for unit and integration test coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915785/integrating-jacoco-with-sonar-for-unit-and-integration-test-coverage) (autdated its prity based on old maven and sonar stuff and our sonar is a bit newer (6.3.1)).

But when I run it the test seems to have 0% so obviously I’m doing something wrong. Some in put on where I did go wrong would be nice.

My main Pom:

```
      <properties>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>             
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <argLine>-Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m</argLine>
      </properties>
        ...
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>agent-for-ut</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>agent-for-it</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-site</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Ive been messing with for my feeling a whole day and have not found a clear cut answer what I am doing wrong. So some input would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

well the coverage for both unit and integration tests is a bit fragile...

The configuration you have looks ok. I think what may happens is that the "argLine" property is replaced or not correctly set for the surefire or failsafe plugin. If you run the mvn goals with -X have a close look what happens when failsafe starts what its value is. The argLine should contain the jacoco agent to collect the coverage information.

Another thing: failsafe might write the coverage results into the same jacoco.exec file as surefire.

What I've done (not sure if it's the smartest of all ways): put all things in a profile and use custom properties for the jacoco-plugin and seperate files for the coverage so the sonar report can pick them up:

The sonar-jacoco-listeners is only required if you want to know what test covers which production code. In sonar this is then shown in the green bar what tests called the code.

Other than that:

The pom has some properties:

```
    <surefire.jvm.args></surefire.jvm.args>
    <failsafe.jvm.args></failsafe.jvm.args>
    <jacoco.append>true</jacoco.append>
</properties>
```

These can be set if needed and the config uses its own properties to not conflict with the argLine (which is the default for both surefire and failsafe)

The sonar.jacoco.reportPath can be used to write one file for all maven modules, in case some integration tests are in a different module and you want to measure the coverage as well (not too nice code-wise, but well... reality and stuff):

```
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
```

Here my coverage profile: (adopt the includes: my/packages/* pattern below!)

```
 <profile>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- prepare configuration for surefire tests -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-agent</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                                <append>true</append>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- prepare configuration for failsafe integration tests -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-agent-integration</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.argLine</propertyName>
                                <append>true</append>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>my/packages/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                        <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine} ${surefire.jvm.args}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>${jacoco.agent.it.argLine} ${failsafe.jvm.args}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

So the principle is the same, setup the jacoco agent in the correct phase and run the tests. I assume the jacoco agent is not properly setup or your argLine conflicts with something happening during your build.

Comment: Ill look in to this later today. If it is waht you think its going to be easy to fix.